# Receiving an email on localhost (kubernetes pod)

Tags: javascript, email, testing, kubernetes, cypress

I have a following issue:

I'm writing an integration test (cypress) for resetting password. The issue is, that right now I send the url (with key needed to reset the password) to users email. Email must be real (so eg. something@something.comething).
I wanted to use something like mailhog for this sake, but I don't think it's possible in this case, since I send api request from frontend to backend with en email that requested password change, then backend sends a message to this email address with the url (so I can't do it directly from frontend and I'd like to avoid backend changes in this case).

Is there some service, that I could use, that would eg. run in kubernetes pod or just straight on localhost, to "pretend" to be a real email, so I could signup with it and then reset the password for it? It must have some api, that would allow me to get the email value (for the sake of getting the url with reset key).

Comment: It is not clear to me what the issue with mailhog would be. Otherwise there's m242/mailhog, which is pretty similar

Comment: As far as I understand, if the frontend and backend are running on the same physical machine, MailHog intercepts all outgoing emails. Regardless of which email address is used. All end up in the same account.